# Image Augmentation of Siamese CNN

Tags: keras

I have a task to compare two images and check whether they are of the same class (using Siamese CNN). Because I have a really small data set, I want to use keras imageDataGenerate.
I have read through the documentation and have understood the basic idea. However, I am not quite sure how to apply it to my use case, i.e. how to generate two images and a label that they are in the same class or not.
Any help would be greatly appreciated?

P.S. I can think of a much more convoluted process using sklearn's extract_patches_2d but I feel there is an elegant solution to this.

Edit: It looks like creating my own data generator may be the way to go. I will try this approach.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399866/triplet-siamese-and-softmax-in-tensorflow for some ideas

Comment: thank you, i will look into it.